# Partitioning a LVM2_member partition

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, system-installation, lvm

I've installed the ubuntu 14.04 server and used the option "guided use the entire disk and configure LVM" to format my disk, when prompted about size of partition I've set 60GB, but now when I take a look at `lsblk` I see that all the HardDisk is already partitioned to sda5 and 60 GB to system `/`.

```
NAME                           FSTYPE        SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda                                        465.8G
├─sda1                         ext2          243M /boot
├─sda2                                         1K
└─sda5                         LVM2_member 465.5G
  ├─Pitcairn--vg-root (dm-0)   ext4         47.9G /
  └─Pitcairn--vg-swap_1 (dm-1) swap            8G [SWAP]
sdb                                        465.8G
sdc                                        931.5G
sdd                                        465.8G
```

Is there the possibility to use the "unpartitioned?" space of `sda5` to make another partition ??

Answer (score 1):

Already found my answer for this question.

I've used `lvcreate -L 3G -n lv-disk Pitcairn-vg` to create a new logical volume, I've did not recognized that what I was managing was logical volumes until I search for LVM in google.

For more information: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/40702/how-to-manage-and-use-lvm-logical-volume-management-in-ubuntu/